# Javascript regex match on a string up to brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to work out a regex for a while now and still cannot get my desired results. Any help would be much appreciated!

Example:

I have previously been using :

```
new RegExp(`^\\s*${keyword}\\s*$`, 'i');
```

To find an exact match on entered keyword/phrase for example :

```
let keyword = 'build',
    keywordTest = new RegExp(`^\\s*${keyword}\\s*$`, 'i');


//user supplied 
let value1 = 'build',
    value2 = 'build something';

let matches1 = keywordTest.test(value1); // true - correct
let matches2 = keywordTest.test(value2); // false - correct
```

But I now have a new use case where square brackets can be supplied as labels e.g. :

```
let value3 = 'build [new build]';

let matches3 = keywordTest.test(value3); // false - but needs to be true
```

Here's a codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mprzgV

I've tried to use a negative lookahead, but haven't really got close to what I need.

Note : This is actually a regex that gets directly applied to a mongo database query, hence not just using javascript to split the string first.

Comment: First of all `'\'` should be escaped in strings like `'\\'`.

Comment: Apart from `'\\'` issue you have used `[...]` that makes it a character class.

Comment: What **exactly** are you expecting that regex to match in the string `build [new build]`?

Comment: `new RegExp(^${keyword}$|^${keyword} \\[.*?\\]$, 'i')` works for me

Comment: ^ thanks, had copied over my example wrong

Comment: @kaddath Looks perfect, big help thanks !